# Linux Sound Drivers - Recompiling kernel with ehcd-hcd module

Tags: linux, audio, kernel, linux-mint

I just installed Linux Mint and I am trying to get my usb soundcard to work. I am completely new to Linux so I have only been learning about all the important parts of the OS this afternoon. No one I know has compiled kernel so I can't ask anyone.

I am following instructions on this site:

http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Benutzer/BigMc#Final-setup-of-US-122L-US-144

"Recompile your Kernel with ehcd-hcd as a module: Instructions for Ubuntu (german) Change "Device Drivers -> USB support -> EHCI HCD (USB 2.0) support)" to "M" when configuring. Make sure you also install the kernel headers."

I know how to do any of these processes. Someone mentioned a package manager. Is recompiling basically in layman's terms reinstallation? Where do I go to the change device drivers?

Cheers

Edit: I am attempting to be able to use my Tascam US-144 on Linux Mint. Apparently, to use it properly it has to regress to functionality of a former unit (US-122), so according to the instructions a USB port has to be USB 1.0, rather than USB 2.0.

I've tried using that ndis**** programme for wireless drivers but with no success.

Comment: The instructions you quoted look insane to me. Surely the Ubuntu kernel already has ehci-hcd as a module. I can't read German and the site apparently requires a login to view the page anyway. I suggest you ignore what you've read there and describe your original problem here to get some better advice. ANd include the output of the command `lsusb`.

Comment: It makes a little more sense now. They want you to downgrade the USB 2.0 driver (ehci-hcd) from Y to M. Still mostly insane though. I wonder if there's a way to tell the kernel that a specific USB device should be operated at the lower speed...